# Is there anything wrong with edits?

Tags: support

Recently I have found a way to earn good points by improving questions like do some formatting or add some tags.

But I have figured out a person is rejecting my edits. Is there anything wrong I am doing? Do I have to stop what I am doing? Please suggest.

See these screenshots for reference:
[image]

And also this one:
[image]

**Update:**

I have checked that particular user's rejection rate. Is it fair?
[image]

A user Rakesh Donga, has done some good formatting in the question but it is also rejected:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/146301

Comment: https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1155/useful-tips-for-review-suggested-edit/1156#1156

Answer (score 5):

We have reviewed on your rejected edit request.

At first edit, I don't think Rutvee is wrong that case, your edit does not enough content to improve the question quality by adding a tag and a highlighted text.
So, in this case, she might be right.

But in the second case, your edit has enough content to improve question quality as you have added a few useful tags on the question. In this case, Rutvee is wrong.

Regarding,Rakesh Donga edit on that question does have not enough content, only highlight text and alignment does not improve the question. He can add more content and tags that will improve edit quality.

As a community member, I am requesting to you all, before rejecting any edit request or doing edit, please view the edit properly and also add some usefully content to your edit and don't add only simple text highlight and a single tag added.

Hope, you guys understand my word.And keep your good work at MSE,

Comment: You nailed it buddy....

Comment: "alignment does not improve the question" .... I disagree in this. Code formating improves readability so I'll approve them. (Btw ... got most of my fist rep for such edit ... i hate bad aligned code :P)

Comment: Agreed with @sv3n, code alignment also improve questions. Also, code added in between sentences should also be used in code styling. I think this type of edits should be approved

Comment: @sv3n,  Code formatting improves the quality but some cases, i have seen that some user formatting over already formatted content and that is no meaning full.